# Rails inline form with form_tag with Bootstrap 3

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have this form:

```
<%= form_tag items_path, {method: :get, :class => "form-inline"} do %>
    <%= text_field_tag :query, params[:query] %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search", name: nil, class: "btn btn-default" %>   
<% end %>
```

As you can see, I'm trying to add the "form-inline" class to this form, but am doing so unsuccessfully with the present code. I've seen examples of passing html options to a form_for helper, but couldn't find out how to do it properly using form_tag and the path url generator (in my case, `items_path`). Help please? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Give this `form_tag` a try, i.e. get rid of the braces around the options.

```
<%= form_tag items_path, method: :get, :class => "form-inline" do %>
    <%= text_field_tag :query, params[:query] %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search", name: nil, class: "btn btn-default" %>   
<% end %>
```

Here is the `form` tag this generates:

```
<form action="/items" class="form-inline" method="get">
```

Comment: Bingo. Thank you. Any idea why the html options don't need to be passed in a hash? I assumed that they would, like in the button helper.

Comment: @settheline, my answer was derived from this pull request: https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/995ab46a08e2e5747b63c75521ab8f5ca2bf922e

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @vee's answer, you can make better use of Bootstrap by adding more of its classes. Using [HAML](http://haml.info/):

```
= form_tag items_path, method: :get, class: 'form-inline' do
  .form-group
    = search_field_tag :query, params[:query],
      placeholder: 'Search for something',
      size: 40,
      class: 'form-control'
    = submit_tag 'Search', name: nil, class: 'btn btn-default'
```

Also note my use of `search_field_tag` instead of `text_field_tag`.